# When was divorce made illegal again in Ireland?

Tags: ireland, law, sociology, marriage

Divorce has been legal in the UK for a long time (since Henry VII obviously). Ireland was part of the UK since 1800 ([Act of Union of 1800](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_of_Union_1800)), so I assume that civil divorce was legal in Ireland in the 19th century (right?).

However Ireland only recently legalised civil divorce in 1995 ([Fifteenth Amendment of the Constitution of Ireland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteenth_Amendment_of_the_Constitution_of_Ireland)), so at what point was civil divorce made *illegal* in Ireland?

Comment: General reference, methinks? Voting to close.

Comment: General Reference? What do you mean? I'm asking a clear, objective quetion that can be answered definitvely about a legal situation in the past.

Comment: As in, 5 minutes on Google could answer the question for you, easily. :-P

Comment: General reference? This site is the general reference +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was made illegal in Republican Ireland in [1937](http://www.jstor.org/pss/650964). Probably as a reaction to England broadening its laws on the subject.

Comment: Why would UK's laws have mattered in Ireland by '37? By then it was an independent state.

Comment: @Rory Moral panic effect?